# pass parameters to asyntask

Tags: android, parameter-passing

I have a problem, is that I use to control a thread AsynTask and I call AsynTask only once, but now I want to do is to call more than once, but of course for that I have to spend a few parameters, but do not know how to do, I've tried thousands ways but does not work. Here I leave my code:

```
     public class leer_registros extends Activity {
    TextView text, depurar;
    EditText reg,ip;
    Button boton;
    float resultado;
    AccionesScada accionesScada = new AccionesScada();


    InetAddress addr = null;        //direccion del esclavo
    int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;//puerto por defecto 502 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblRegistro);
        ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIp);
        reg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtReg);
        depurar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdepurar); 
        boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVerRegistro);
        depurar.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    public class conectar extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        int m;
        int startReg;
        int count;
        String dirIP;
        String dirReg;



        public conectar(String aux,String aux1) {
        this.dirIP=aux;
            this.dirReg=aux1;


            try {

                //IP address;
                //aux1 = ip.getText().toString();
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(dirIP);
                //aux = reg.getText().toString();
                startReg = Integer.decode(dirReg).intValue();
                depurar.setText(dirIP);
                //Reg = startReg[0];

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MODBUS","IP error", e);

            }
        }

         protected  Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {



             m = accionesScada.conectar(addr, port);
             resultado = accionesScada.LeerRegistro(startReg, count);

             return null;


         }


         protected void onPostExecute(Integer bytes) {
             if(m==1){
                 depurar.setText("conectado!!!");
                 depurar.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
                 String resul = String.valueOf(resultado);
                 text.setText(resul); 
         }
    }


    public void verRegistro(View v)  {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        //IP address;
         final String aux = ip.getText().toString();
         final String aux1 = reg.getText().toString();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override

        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{ 
                         depurar.setText(aux1);
                        /*conectar conectamos = new conectar();
                        conectamos.execute(aux,aux1);*/
                        conectar conectamos = new conectar(aux,aux1);
                        conectamos.execute();

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.d("MODBUS", "Error Timertask");
                    }

                }

            });

        }

        }; 
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000);
    }

}
```

I want you to pass to the function its: aux and aux1.
Please help me!.
Thanks.

Comment: you can pass it to the constructor of asynctask or doInbackground directly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor inside  Async Task to pass parameters to it. Like this

Call to Async task

```
new conectar(url,_payload,method,context).execute();
```

AsycTask with constructor

```
private static class Conectar extends
            AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Integer> {


        private final String mUrl;
        private final String mPayload;
        private final HttpMethod mMethod;
        private final Context mContext;

        public Conectar(String url,String _payload, HttpMethod method,final Context context) {

            mContext = context;
            mUrl=url;
            mPayload=_payload;
            mMethod=method;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... vParams) {
            ResponseWrapper user = null;
            String url = mUrl;
```

Comment: when i call to asynTask: new conectar(aux,aux1).execute(); I get a problem and tells me to connect is not defined

Comment: I have already updated my code, but I'll put it like you also say, the problem is that when I put conectamos.execute not enter. Ie not within the asyntask

Comment: no, not resolved and I'm desperate, I've now updated my code and I've outlined above.
my problem is still not working the pass parameters ie a good time to connect the parameters but, when I call accionesScada.conectar (..,) I get an error and does not connect, as if did not read well what happened parameters .

I put my code updated to see if there is an error ... thank you very much =)

Answer (score 0):

```
conectar conectamos = new conectar();
conectamos.execute(1, 2, 3);// Pass the parameter like this



// Get the parameter like this
protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... urls) {
  int parameter1=urls[0];
  int parameter1=urls[1];
  int parameter1=urls[2];


}
```

**Edited:-**

As you declare the first Argument as Integer but you are passing String.
so change it to string and it will work for.

```
public class conectar extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Integer>
```

Comment: step the parameters as follows:String aux = new String();
   String aux1 = new String();
   aux1 = ip.getText().toString();                             aux = reg.getText().toString();                               conectar conectamos = new conectar();    conectamos.execute(aux,aux1); and i have a problem,apparently not entering the function AsyncTask why??

Comment: @Isma9 the problem is b'coz you declare Integer for first argument in AsynTask.. But you need to pass string values so changes the Data type to string. see my updated answer,

Comment: i edited mi post, see my post.i have a problem,apparently not entering the function AsyncTask.